# No such property: exampleInstance for class: test3.ExampleController

Tags: search, grails, find

Domain

```
class Example {
   String title
   Date releaseDate
   String author
   Boolean paperback
   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

Controller

```
class ExampleController {
   def scaffold = true

   def search = {
      exampleInstance = Example.findAllByTitleIlike("${params.q}%",[max:10, offset:0, sort:"title", order:"asc"])

      redirect(action: "list",params)
      return
   }

   def list = {
      params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
      [exampleInstanceList: Example.list(params),
       exampleInstanceTotal: Example.count()]
   }
}
```

View

```
<div id="search">
   <g:form url='[controller: "example", action: "search"]' id="search" name="search" method="get">
      <g:textField name="q" value="${params.q}" />
      <input type="submit" value="Find" />
   </g:form>
</div>
```

Please Help me is how

```
Error URI /test3/example/search Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message No such property: exampleInstance for class: test3.ExampleController
```

Comment: The exampleInstance variable is not being passed from the controller to the gsp.

Answer (score 1):

Use render instead of redirect and pass all the model that are required for the list page.
`def search = {`
`def exampleInstance= Example.findAllByTitleIlike("${params.q}%",[max:10, offset:0, sort:"title", order:"asc"])`
`render( view:list, model:[ exampleInstance:exampleInstance, params:params ] )`

Comment: You need a `def` there before `exampleInstance=`

Comment: IF I WANT SEARCH 2 DOMAIN 2 FIELD HOW I UPDATE IN CONTROLLER

Comment: i didn't get what you are trying to say. Do you mean to say that you want to search 2 different fields in one domain or in two different domains?

Comment: ask this as a separate question. Give the exact domains details and on which field you want to search.
P.S: you can accept this answer if it has helped you in solving your question.